# Cannot read base 64 string with PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to draw a background image directly into my canvas background by reading a base 64 string from another file `background_image.py`. According to the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) these lines should be working:

```
import background_image

background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=background_image.background_image) 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=background_image, anchor=NW)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Comment: What does the imported variable `background_image` refer to? Importing a value and then reassigning something else to that name is not good practice. It makes the code harder to understand and debug.